# Unable to retrieve data objects from my JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, html

I've created a JSON file to call out the name of a list of beers to display ABV and country but I am unable to display the results on the webpage.  I was able to get the select tag to drop down the list, but when selecting a beer, it will only show the selected results as "undefined."

Here is the JS code I have so far...

```
var $select = $("#beerListing");
var beer = Array();
var country = Array();

$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
  $select.html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < data['beer'].length; i++)
    $select.append('<option id="' + data["beer"][i]['id'] + '">' + data["beer"][i]["beer_name"] + '</option>');

  for (x in data) {
    if (beer.indexOf(data[x].beer_name) < 0) {
      var y = beer.length;
      beer[y] = data[x].beer_name;
      country[y] = data[x].brewery_country;
    }
  }

  showBeerList();
});

function showBeerList() {
  var select = document.getElementById('beerListing');

  for (var i = 0; i < beer.length; i++) {
    var obj = document.createElement("option");
    obj.text = beer[i];
    obj.value = i;
    select.appendChild(obj);
  }
}

function getBeerInfo(picked) {
  if (picked == "Pick Your Poison...") {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = beer[picked];
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country[picked];
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>LCBO API TESTING</h1>

    <select name="beerlist" id="beerListing" class="form-control" onchange="getBeerInfo(this.value)">

    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <label id="name">--</label>
    <br>
    <label>Country:</label>
    <label id="country">--</label>
    <br>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSON List called data.json

```
{
    "beer": [{
        "beer_name": "Organic Devon Cider",
        "brewery_name": "Luscombe Organic Drinks",
        "beer_type": "Cider",
        "beer_abv": "4.9",
        "beer_ibu": "0",
        "comment": "",
        "venue_name": "The Anchor & Hope",
        "venue_city": "London",
        "venue_state": "Greater London",
        "brewery_country": "England"
    }, {
        "beer_name": "Beer A",
        "brewery_name": "Beer A",
        "beer_type": "Cider",
        "beer_abv": "4.9",
        "beer_ibu": "0",
        "comment": "",
        "venue_name": "Beer",
        "venue_city": "New York",
        "venue_state": "New York",
        "brewery_country": "USA"
    }]
}
```

Comment: please post the json file as well

Comment: I will add a small JSON list shortly

Comment: @S.Demarco i fixed your JSON a little bit but you have no comma in it, I didn't want to fix that as well if it's actually the way your data is. That's wrong, there should be a comma between the 2 beer objects },{

Comment: There is a comma between the two objects

Comment: Your data has the beer list in a `beer` property, after getting the data your outer for loop correctly accesses the data but your inner `for (var x in data)` should be `for (var x in data.beer)` with corresponding change in the body of that loop.

Comment: What does "call out" mean?

Comment: To retrieve objects/data from a json file, torazaburo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemed to be adding the options to the select element twice and using for-in which iterates properties, not entries in an array.

Below snippet will not work as requires external data source.

```js
var $select = $("#beerListing") ;
var beer = Array();
var country = Array();

$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {

$select.html('');

for (var i = 0; i < data.beer.length; i = i + 1) {
  if (beer.indexOf(data.beer[i].beer_name) < 0) {
    beer.push(data.beer[i].beer_name);
    country.push(data.beer[i].brewery_country);
  }
}
  
showBeerList();  
}


function showBeerList() {
    var select = document.getElementById('beerListing');
    for (var i = 0; i < beer.length; i++) {
        var obj = document.createElement("option");
        obj.text = beer[i];
        obj.value = i;
        select.appendChild(obj);

    }
}

function getBeerInfo(picked) {
  if (picked == "Pick Your Poison...") {
    location.reload();
    } 
  else {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = beer[picked];
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country[picked];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>LCBO API TESTING</h1>

<select name="beerlist" id="beerListing" class="form-control" onchange="getBeerInfo(this.value)">

    </select>
<br>
<label>Name:</label>
<label id="name">--</label>
<br>
<label>Country:</label>
    <label id="country">--</label>
    <br>
```

Comment: Vanquished, thanks. But I still need to retrieve the data from the json file and not from the assigned data statement.  The app.json needs to be include for me to call all beer objects

Comment: @S.Demarco Updated to use the ajax data fetch. Unable to test as relies on external data JSON file.

Comment: Thank you, vanquished.  I will try your code and let you know if will work

Comment: Vanquished, Thank you, your code works.  I can know update my old app and run a new beer object.

Comment: @S.Demarco Excellent - can you tick my answer if it helped? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/bu7pkb5f/1/

What are you doing with:

```
if (beer.indexOf(data[x].beer_name) < 0) {

    var y = beer.length;
    beer[y] = data[x].beer_name;
    country[y] = data[x].brewery_country;

}
```

I don't understand it but it's creating a third item in the list after the two real beer entries are processed. I left it commented out in the fiddle so you can check it out for yourself.

Comment: Use beer.push() to add another entry to the beer array, same for country.

Comment: Serg, the only problem is that the list is more than 2 beer objects.  My json file has over 1800 beer objects.  Assigning two objects is fine but 1800 will take up a lot of lines.  That's why I want to retrieve the objects in a json file.  Also, the second option was from another json app where the objects were called in a call script that worked until URL that I was using is no longer working

Comment: @S.Demarco I'm loading the data from your JSON file. I had to paste it into the jsfiddle because I can't make an ajax request to it from there. Nothing is manual, you can make that JSON have 300 objects and my code will work as it currently is. No changes required.

Comment: Thanks, Serg.  I will test your code out and let you know if I got it to work